# how to delay a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I want to delay a request for some milliseconds.

I am doing 3 ajax call which jquery when inside a for loop.that length of the for loop is 20 max.

Means I am doing nearly 60 request with few seconds.In chrome,firefox ,safary and opera it has no problem but in IE its aborting the request.

My For Loop

```
for (index in personScoreCollection.collection) {
        //Get the 4th and 5th score simultaniously.
        $.when(UserSearch(index), UsabilityScore(index), UserConnection(index)).done();
    }
```

all the methods having one one ajax request.

you can see the error how ie aborting the request here

[image http://s24.postimg.org/q0zj3vwhg/Error_Message.jpg](http://s24.postimg.org/q0zj3vwhg/Error_Message.jpg)

How to delay or hold the request using java script.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `.done` call itself to trigger the next batch of AJAX calls:

```
var keys = Object.keys(personScoreCollection.collection);

(function next() {
    if (keys.length) {
       var index = keys.shift();
       $.when(UserSearch(index),
              UsabilityScore(index),
              UserConnection(index)
       ).done(function(a, b, c) {
                  // process results
       }, next);  // recurse
    }
})();  // start loop immediately
```

The code makes an array of the required keys, and just shifts one key from that array at a time, then making the three required AJAX calls.  Only once all three have completed does it then start the next batch.

To loop, it takes advantage of how `.done` can be passed *multiple* callbacks, each of which will be called in turn.  If you were to reverse those two callbacks you could actually start the next batch of (asynchronous) fetches while the current set of results is being processed.

Note that this loop will abort if any of the AJAX calls fail because the `.done` function's callbacks will not be invoked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setTimeout function to delay some work.
An example :

```
var ms_pause = 50; // time between request in milliseconds
var counter = 1;

for (index in personScoreCollection.collection) {
    //Get the 4th and 5th score simultaniously.
    setTimeout((function(context_index){
        return function(){
            $.when(UserSearch(context_index), UsabilityScore(context_index), UserConnection(context_index)).done();
        }
    })(index), ms_pause * counter);
    counter += 1;
}
```